# Lisp Format Procedure

Tags: list, lisp, integer, format

Im starting to program in Lisp and having an hard time with the Format function.

My objective is to print a list of integer sublists as N integers for line. For example:

'((1 2 3)
  (4 5 6)
 (7 8 9))

should be printed as

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

I tried using iteration in the format procedure, but I failed.

What I wrote was:

```
(format t "~{~S ~}" list)
```

But with this I get the sublists as "(1 2 3)" instead of "1 2 3", so i tried:

```
(format t "~:{ ~S ~}" list)
```

this time I got into the sublists but only printed the first element, so I stepped in and re-wrote the function to:

```
(format t "~:{ ~S ~S ~S ~}" list)
```

It works for sublists with 3 elements, but how can I make it work for n elements?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
(format t "~{~%~{~A~^ ~}~}"  '((1 2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9)))
```

prints

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```